# MFMessageComposeViewController showed without cancel button and title

Tags: ios, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, cancel-button

My app has a feature to allow user sending SMS to their contacts who haven't register our app to invite them. I implemented it as follows several weeks ago and it works well:

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [MFMessageComposeViewController new];
    NSDictionary *contact = self.notRegisterdUser[index]; // got from reading user's contacts if allowed
    controller.recipients = @[contact.allKeys[0]];
    controller.body = @"some message";
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But yesterday I found the feature was broken as it did not show Cancel button like this:

[image: MFMessageComposeViewController issue]

I have tested it on iOS 8.1, 8.2, 8.3 and 8.4, it exist for all. Is there something changed or I did wrong?

Comment: i think you are testing it on simulator. try to run this on device and i ope it works perfectly!

Comment: When you click the space where these buttons should be placed. It's getting dismiss or send? I think you set the same color that's why it's invisible.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati I tested it on my device, not simulator.

Comment: @LucasHuang Nothing happened, just like there is no Cancel button. I did not set the BarButtonItem appearance, actually, I deleted all of the appearance setting code to verify whether I have done what you said.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [FDFullscreenPopGesture](https://github.com/forkingdog/FDFullscreenPopGesture) from forkingdog? If so then this is the problem. The FDFullscreenPopGesture category somehow got conflict with the pop-uped sms view. There is an [issue](https://github.com/forkingdog/FDFullscreenPopGesture/issues/14) talking about that.

The solution was provided in the issue and I've checked:

> You should disable it when using MFMessageComposeViewController. Notice that setting fd_viewControllerBasedNavigationBarAppearanceEnabled to NO doesn't work. A temporary solution might be:

```
(void)fd_pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated { 
    //Add this: 
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[MFMessageComposeViewController class]]) { 
        [self fd_pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
        return; 
    } 
    ...... 
}
```

It might be a late answer but hope it works for others.

Comment: Yes that's right. Sorry for being so late to send respond. Due to my low reputation I cannot up-vote your answer.